# Apache is requesting .htaccess from user directory which is parent dir to DocumentRoot

Tags: linux, permissions, apache-http-server, htaccess

1. I have my website/blog in `/home/tarach/www/tarach.net`

   2. All files and directories starting from `/home/tarach/www` are to user: `tarach`, group: `www-data` ( apache httpd group )
   3. I've setup virtualhost `tarach.net` to point to dir from 1)
   4. Apache is requesting access to `.htaccess` file in `/home/tarach`
   5. After creating file `/home/tarach/.htaccess` and setting group of that file and my home directory to `www-data` it started working. Earlier I had message : `[Thu Jul 09 04:13:28 2015] [crit] [client 79.185.210.150] (13)Permission denied: /home/tarach/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable, referer: http://tarach.net/`

I don't want my Apache webserver to be accessing my home directory. What should I do to eliminate it.

**vhost configuration**
[image]

I've pasted it as an image because looks like editor can't handle Apache configuration at all and gives a lot of display errors. http://pastebin.com/vpAFQ6PP

Answer (score 1):

Apache will search recursively up the tree for .htaccess files, on *every* access, which is why .htaccess files (i.e. anything besides `AllowOverride none`) is a bad idea if you want high performance. If you can, put the directives in the config itself and turn off `AllowOverride`.

Perhaps Adding a `<Directory>` segment with `AllowOverride none` for the parent directory may help.

Comment: Adding `AllowOverride none` for `<Directory />` triggers `you don't have permission to access / on this server.` and in error.log `(13)Permission denied: access to / denied`. I'm using apache2 aptitude version `2.2.22-13+deb7u4`